# aerender not exiting after completion

Tags: command-line, window, after-effects

I'm working with the aerender command to make some automated renders.
It works and exits fine on osx, but no matter how I try (powershell, node spawn, command prompt), the command never exits when I run it on windows: it does its job, but then hangs there forever.

Has anyone had this issue, and how did you solve it?

Comment: did u ever solve this? got the same problem!

Comment: No, but the problem has become intermittent, so it's harder to track.It seems to me that starting my script as a windows service makes this less likely, but I need to investigate more.